# Laravel compare timestamps in where statement

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4, php-carbon

I have a block of code in which I am passing a Carbon date that looks like this:

```
2017-08-18 22:53:50.031922
```

And want to compare it to `created_at` time stamps of some records. However, it seems that the records are not being filtered out; is the comparison in the where statement valid?

```
$test = Auth::user()->tests()->with([
    'participants.testRecords' => function ($query) use ($latestCapture) {
        $query->select('id', 'score', 'test_id', 'participant_id', 'capture_timestamp', 'score', 'created_at');
        $query->where('test_records.created_at', '>', $latestCapture);
}])->findOrFail($id)->toArray();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$latestCapture` is instancej Carbon, you should rather use here:

```
$latestCapture->toDateTimeString()
```

to make sure you pass valid date string.

There is also one more thing - you should make sure `created_at` is filled in PHP and not in MySQL (this is default in Laravel) - if it's not you can expect time shifts when you have different time zones in PHP and MySQL

Comment: Great points -- the toDateTimeString() seemingly fixed my problem.